# Can SQL Server synchronize with Android and iOS apps using MS Synchronization Framework?

Tags: android, .net, ios, sql-server-2008, microsoft-sync-framework

I have developed my application in wpf with prism framework.

My application database server is SQL Server. And I want to use this SQL Server with Android and iOS. Now I want to synchronize my application with Android and iOS using the MS Sync framework.

**Edit**

Actually my desktop app maintains contact book and i want to sync android and iphone  contact book with it. Is that possible using bluetooth because i found that sync framework can work with bluetooth protocol.

Answer (score 0):

there is no Sync Framework for iOS or Android.

the closest you can get to is the [Sync Framework Toolkit](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Sync-Framework-Toolkit-4dc10f0e)

i think there's sample there for iPhone. for Android, you will have to write your own client sync provider.